# Como hacer un vector precargado en c# .net

Tags: c#, array

Estoy intentando hacer un vector precargado que contenga legajo, nombre y apellido, estuve intentando hacer esto pero hay algo que no me cierra.

```
object[] first=new object [] {"00","01",02"};
object[] second=new object [] {"00","01",02"};
```

O si no.

string vectoralumno = "100,Mateo,Alvarez";

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema.. crear un array, o cargarle datos?

Answer (score 0):

No esta correcto ya que te faltan las comillas antes de 02, debería quedar:

```cs
object[] first=new object [] {"00","01","02"};
object[] second=new object [] {"00","01","02"};
```